# Run a piece of JavaScript as soon as a third-party script fails to load

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I provide a JavaScript widget to several web sites, which they load asynchronously. My widget in turn needs to load a script provided by another party, outside my control.

There are several ways to check whether that script has successfully loaded. However, I also need to run different code if that script load has failed.

The obvious tools that don't work include:

- I'm not willing to use JavaScript libraries, such as jQuery. I need a very small script to minimize my impact on the sites that use my widget.
- I want to detect the failure as soon as possible, so using a timer to poll it is undesirable. I wouldn't mind using a timer as a last resort on old browsers, though.
- I've found the `<script>` tag's `onerror` event to be unreliable in some major browsers. (It seemed to depend on which add-ons were installed.)
- Anything involving `document.write` is right out. (Besides that method being intrinsically evil, my code is loaded asynchronously so `document.write` may do bad things to the page.)

I had a previous solution that involved loading the `<script>` in a new `<iframe>`. In that iframe, I set a `<body onload=...>` event handler that checked whether the `<script onload=...>` event had already fired. Because the `<script>` was part of the initial document, not injected asynchronously later, `onload` only fired after the network layer was done with the `<script>` tag.

However, now I need the script to load in the parent document; it can't be in an iframe any more. So I need a different way to trigger code as soon as the network layer has given up trying to fetch the script.

I read "[Deep dive into the murky waters of script loading](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)" in an attempt to work out what ordering guarantees I can count on across browsers.

If I understand the techniques documented there:

- I need to place my failure-handling code in a separate `.js` file.
- Then, on certain browsers I can ensure that my code runs only after the third-party script either has run or has failed. This requires browsers that support either:

  - Setting the `<script async>` attribute to false via the DOM,
  - or using `<script onreadystatechange=...>` on IE 6+.

Despite looking at the [async support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=async), I can't tell whether I can rely on script ordering in enough browsers for this to be feasible.

So how can I reliably handle failure during loading of a script I don't control?

Comment: what about checking for the existence of something in the script. Like if the script contains a certain object, look for that

Comment: @CrayonViolent, it's easy to determine that the script has loaded. However, I need to know when to check. If I check too soon, the script won't have even been downloaded yet. I need to know how to tell the difference between "hasn't loaded yet" and "won't ever load because we gave up". If I can be sure that my check runs after the script has been processed, then I'm all set.

Comment: well, imo checking for a unique thing within the script will be your most reliable way.  But i really don't think there's a way to do that without using `setTimeout` every 100ms or so for x amount of time and giving up after that. This is what I do in situations like this, and so far I haven't found a better method; I just don't think one exists at this time :/

Comment: IOW I have not found any cross-browser reliable way to answer the question "did this script load or did it return a 404 or timeout or what?" so the best fallback I've found is to just check for something unique to the file and check for it every 100ms for a little while based on what I know about the script and server running on it; anywhere from 500ms-2s usually) and then assume not loaded after that

Comment: @CrayonViolent, have you investigated the HTML5 promises for script ordering, as covered by the "Deep dive" article I linked? I think there should at least be a solution for modern browsers based on that, but I'm hoping someone has investigated already and can share their experience.

Comment: I read the article, and unless I missed something, that article goes into 'guaranteeing' order of execution (and it seems the bottom line "best" way to do it is to just keep doing normal script includes..), not really about checking if something actually loaded or failed to load.

Comment: @CrayonViolent, sure, I think you're reading it right. The hard part, as I see it, is executing the failure/success check at the right time. If you can be guaranteed that the check executes after the third-party script has definitely either loaded or failed, then you win. Once you can rule out the possibility that "the script hasn't run yet but it still might load later", testing whether the script has already run is easy.

Comment: well that's the problem.. afaik there's no way to do it, except to just put your code that checks for object or w/e in a `setTimeout` and if not found, kick it to `setTimeout` again. wash rinse repeat for anywhere from 500ms to 2s or maybe more if you know server is slower.. and then after x time limit, assume failed to load. IOW there is no guarantee to run it after it's definitely either loaded or failed, because there is no real mechanism to check. Hence using `setTimeout` to check repeatedly and just decide for yourself where to draw the line and say "okay i've checked enough, screw it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've solved the question I asked, though it turns out this doesn't solve the problem I actually had. Oh well. Here's my solution:

We want to run some code after the browser finishes attempting to load a third-party script, so we can check whether it loaded successfully. We accomplish that by constraining the load of a fallback script to happen only after the third-party script has either run or failed. The fallback script can then check whether the third-party script created the globals it was supposed to.

Cross-browser in-order script loading inspired by http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/.

```
var fallbackLoader = doc.createElement(script),
    thirdPartyLoader = doc.createElement(script),
    thirdPartySrc = '<URL to third party script>',
    firstScript = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0];

// Doesn't matter when we fetch the fallback script, as long as
// it doesn't run early, so just set src once.
fallbackLoader.src = '<URL to fallback script>';

// IE starts fetching the fallback script here.

if('async' in firstScript) {
    // Browser support for script.async:
    // http://caniuse.com/#search=async
    //
    // By declaring both script tags non-async, we assert
    // that they need to run in the order that they're added
    // to the DOM.
    fallbackLoader.async = thirdPartyLoader.async = false;
    thirdPartyLoader.src = thirdPartySrc;
    doc.head.appendChild(thirdPartyLoader);
    doc.head.appendChild(fallbackLoader);
} else if(firstScript.readyState) {
    // Use readyState for IE 6-9. (IE 10+ supports async.)
    // This lets us fetch both scripts but refrain from
    // running them until we know that the fetch attempt has
    // finished for the first one.
    thirdPartyLoader.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(thirdPartyLoader.readyState == 'loaded') {
            thirdPartyLoader.onreadystatechange = null;
            // The script-loading tutorial comments:
            // "can't just appendChild, old IE bug
            // if element isn't closed"
            firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(thirdPartyLoader, firstScript);
            firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(fallbackLoader, firstScript);
        }
    };
    // Don't set src until we've attached the
    // readystatechange handler, or we could miss the event.
    thirdPartyLoader.src = thirdPartySrc;
} else {
    // If the browser doesn't support async or readyState, we
    // just won't worry about the case where script loading
    // fails. This is <14% of browsers worldwide according to
    // caniuse.com, and hopefully script loading will succeed
    // often enough for them that this isn't a problem.
    //
    // If that isn't good enough, you might try setting an
    // onerror listener in this case. That still may not work,
    // but might get another small percentage of old browsers.
    // See
    // http://blog.lexspoon.org/2009/12/detecting-download-failures-with-script.html
    thirdPartyLoader.src = thirdPartySrc;
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(thirdPartyLoader, firstScript);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the window's [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror) handler? That will let you detect when most errors occur and you can take appropriate action then. As a fallback for any issues not caught this way you can also protect your own code with try/catch.

You should also check that the third-party script actually loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" onload="loaded=1" src="thirdparty.js"></script>
```

Then check if it loaded:

```
window.onload = function myLoadHandler() {
  if (loaded == null) {
    // The script doesn't exist or couldn't be loaded!
  }
}
```

You can check which script caused the error using the `url` parameter.

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
  if (url == third_party_script_url) {
    // Do alternate code
  } else {
    return false; // Do default error handling
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of portably detecting script errors, but only those errors from a particular `<script>` tag? I don't want to detect errors in scripts I didn't trigger. And as I said, I know how to use the `script onload` event, but that doesn't help me detect failures promptly.

Comment: The `window.onerror` event didn't fire for me in a quick test with Firefox 17, even when the script failed to load. And if it had fired, I suspect it would fall afoul of same-origin restrictions, as described here: http://www.schemehostport.com/2011/10/x-script-origin-we-hardly-knew-ye.html In short, I'm skeptical that this line of development is going to work, but it was worth trying, and I appreciate you suggesting it!

Comment: There is a difference between "script failed to load" and "script had an error". If a script is missing (404) the browser will not throw an error but if it does load it will trigger the `onload` method. You can then use `window.onload` to check the status of global vars set in your `script.onload` handler(s).

Comment: I don't expect the third-party script to have errors. It's used by plenty of people. I do expect it to fail to load sometimes, and that's what I need to detect. And I can't use `window.onload` because, as I said, my script is loaded asynchronously, which means it may run after `window.onload` fires.

Comment: But your script wont run BEFORE onload fires. You wanted to know the result of loading the other script as early as possible and `window.onload` IS the earliest moment possible. You can still check for the `loaded` variable at any time after `window.onload` in your own script.

Comment: To clarify: my widget code, which uses the DOM to load the third-party script, is loaded asynchronously and may not have loaded before `window.onload` fires. Therefore if I listen for `window.onload` my event handler not only might run too early--it may never run.

Comment: Even scripts with `async` load before `window.onload`. The only way you can load a script after `window.onload` is through some type of interaction event or setTimeout modifying the DOM after load. Also, have you tried loading the thirdparty script at the top of your own via `@import`?