# How to programmatically determine whether some JavaScript code fails or generates an error

Tags: javascript, html

I have some JavaScript code embedded on a web page. Despite cross browser testing to ensure that the JavaScript runs on a matrix of different operating systems and web browsers, the JavaScript may still fail during execution in the wild.

Is there a way to determine when some JavaScript fails, then log that occurrence, along with some session context that would give some information about what happened? I know about the JavaScript `<noscript>` tag, and the `no-js` style in HTML5, but I'm more concerned about when the JavaScript attempts to run but encounters a problem.

Essentially, I want to find out when my JavaScript code fails to perform, so I can learn more about what happened and fix the problem proactively. Commercial solutions are acceptable.

So far, the closest solution I've found is [Jamey Sharp's method to set a global variable in JavaScript, then check the value of that variable in a later JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20294373/705157).

Comment: You mean `try` and `catch` statements?

Comment: You could wrap all of your code in `try` and `catch` and then post the exception details to a URL on your server that logs all that information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap all your code in a

```
try {
    [code]
} catch (e) {
    [handle error]
}
```

This can be as simple as:

```
function error_wrap(callback) {
    try { callback(); } catch (e) {
        // do ajax to report error
    }
}
error_wrap(function () {
    // my code
});
```

The hard part are events. Whenever an event occurs the error will not be caught.

```
 error_wrap(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error("nope"); // this error will not be caught
    }, 1);
});
```

Make sure you also wrap all your event handlers (and `setTimeout` and `setInterval`).

Incase of `setTimeout` it can look like:

```
function wrappedSetTimeout(callback, ms) {
    return setTimeout(function () { // wrap the function again because we don't want to execute it yet
        error_wrap(callback);
    }, ms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[try/catch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

Example from the Mozilla Developer Network:

```
try {
   throw "myException"; // generates an exception
}
catch (e) {
   // statements to handle any exceptions
   logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
}
```

If you want to log, then you'll have to do an AJAX call to send the error and context to the backend and use your usual logging mecanism there.